# Are there sentimental connotations to the phrase "all grown up"?

Tags: popular-refrains

I tried some internet searches and couldn't get a clear take on this.

If someone makes a comment along the lines of "Look at Chris, all grown up", do most people interpret that at face value? I seem to feel like most of the time I hear that phrase, there is something in the person's voice or delivery that carries some sort of implication.

Said one way, it could imply that Chris was kind of awkward or troublesome or immature when younger but appears to have grown out of it.

Said another way, it could imply that Chris was really "cute" as a kid and is now no longer "cute" as a child would be but impressive in some way as an adult.

Am I making this up?

Comment: However and whenever you say it, it's baby talk. Adults are never all grown up. But 5-yr olds are told "You're a big boy" because they are not.

Comment: It can mean different things. It will depend on the individual example. I'm not sure someone can give an answer listing every possible tone of voice and its meaning.

Comment: It's patronising. Compare "Aren't you all better!" from Sherlock to the violent (but now having to toe the line) agent he had previously dropped onto Mrs Hudson's dustbins from a great height ['Sherlock'; 'A Scandal in Belgravia').

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon to use "all grown up" in a sentimental manner. This is likely to come from a parent as their child passes various milestones of adulthood, like going off to college or buying a car, that reflect independence from their parents.

> Look at our boy, he's all grown up now.

Answer (score 0):

It's patronising, condescending, at least by connotation (which is what OP asks about), though as others point out, it *could* be very sentimental. It should be used with great care:

> **(be) all grown up**
>
> "Grown up" means "adult". But the phrase "grown up" is usually used
> when you're talking to, or talking about, kids. For example, one of
> the most common questions to ask children is:
>
> What do you want to be when you grow up?
>
> This means "What kind of job do you want to have when you become an
> adult?"
>
> The phrase "all grown up" sounds even more cute and child-like than
> "grown up". So if you said to a 19-year-old who you haven't seen in
> several years:
>
> Look at you! You're all grown up!
>
> it would probably be meant as a joke, because you're talking to him as
> if he were a child. The 19-year-old probably wouldn't think it was
> that funny.

[[PhraseMix](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/be-all-grown-up)]

Comment: It could be meant as an endearment. It is not always condescending or patronizing.

Comment: @Lambie is correct. It's often in a parent's lament when they realize their child no longer needs their assistance. Like when sending them off to college.

Comment: The phrase is patronising and condescending when addressed to the person in question, if that person regards it as obvious that he or she is an adult. It may, however, be used in other ways: the parent referred to in Barmar's comment may use it as an exclamation that is addressed to no one in particular.